# Comparing a value from two different array of objects in React.JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am looking for a simple solution to compare just the "session" values from two different arrays of objects using React.JS.

I have:

```
  this.state = {
        dataOne: [
            {
                id: "1",
                session: "10:00",
                value: "10:00"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                session: "10:15",
                value: "10:15"
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                session: "10:30",
                value: "10:30"
            },
            {
                id: "4",
                session: "10:45",
                value: "10:45"
            },
            {
                id: "5",
                session: "11:00",
                value: "11:00"
            },
        ],
        dataTwo: [
            {
                id: "6",
                session: "10:00",
                value: "10:00"
            },
            {
                id: "7",
                session: "10:15",
                value: "10:15"
            },
            {
                id: "8",
                session: "11:30",
                value: "11:30"
            },
            {
                id: "9",
                session: "12:45",
                value: "12:45"
            },
            {
                id: "10",
                session: "13:00",
                value: "13:00"
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Those are the two arrays I need to compare.

I tried the following thing:

```
 if(this.state.dataOne.map(item => item.session) === (this.state.dataTwo.some(item => item.session)) {
       return console.log('true');
 else {
       return console.log('false);
  }
```

Any suggestions? It always returns false to me....

Comment: `console.log` always returns `undefined`

Comment: Are you trying to compare each `session` of `dataOne` with the corresponding index `session` in the second array?

Comment: I don't really know what exact you want to compare. Probably it can work for you: `dataOne.map(item => item.session).sort().join('') === dataTwo.map(item => item.session).sort().join('')`

Comment: Compare them *how*? You said you want to compare them, but that's pretty vague. You can compare them in a hundred different ways.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.map` will return an object(array) and `Array.prototype.some` will return a boolean. Since you are using a strict equal, the expression will always be evaluated to `false`

```
const dataOneSession = this.state.dataOne.map(item => item.session);
const dataTwoSession = this.state.dataTwo.map(item => item.session);

let isAllValueMatched = true;

dataOneSession.forEach((value, i) => {
  if(value !== dataTwoSession[i]) {
    isAllValueMatched = false;
  }
});

if(isAllValueMatched) console.log(true);
else console.log(false);
```

I just corrected the code that you had given, we can write this code in an optimised way if you furnish more information like, are the arrays going to be in same length, will there be a dataThree? etc.

Comment: It possible without extra `map`. And some performance optimisations: `const isAllValueMatched  = dataOne.every(({session}, i) => session === dataTwo[i].session)`

Comment: Yeah I agree. But cannot give such solutions without knowing, dataTwo gonna be the same size as dataOne. no? Could be resulted in an exception. OP has to comment on it.

Comment: The initial idea is that i need to check if one session from the first array is equal to a session in second array.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If arrays' length aren't equal, there's no reason to check them: `const isAllValueMatched = dataOne.length === dataTwo.length && dataOne.every(({session}, i) => session === dataTwo[i].session)`